# I need contacts based on profile

Tags: reporting

Can we create a report on `Contact` based on Profile of the Owner?

Comment: Your question is pretty vague, have you tried something already that did not work?

Comment: The owner of a Contact - a User - has a Profile but a Contact itself is not directly related to Profile.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible. Unfortunately, the contact owner profile name doesn't show up in the list of field in a report on contacts. However, there is a simple workaround. Create a new field on the Contact object of the type formula (text). Then use the formula to get the owner profile (for instance Owner.Profile.Name). After that you can use the new field in your reports.

I hope that will help you.